# For loop using find lacks doesn't properly handle directory names having white space character

Tags: bash, find, whitespace, for-loop

Well i am really stuck at this one.

I have dirs.txt which is as follows:

```
/var/tmp/old files.txt
/var/tmp/old backups.bak
```

dirs.txt file is generated by the script itself.

When i want to use dirs.txt in a for loop like:

```
for dir in `cat dirs.txt` ; do 
    ls -al $dir
done
```

Here is what the command throws:
ls: cannot access /var/tmp/old: No such file or directory

I want the whole filenames to be ls -al'ed but it tries to ls -al /var/tmp/old

How may i correct this from the for loop?

Answer (score 12):

```
cat dirs.txt | while read dir; do
    ls -al "$dir"
done
```

1. When you use the backtick operator the output is split into tokens at each whitespace character. `read`, on the other hand, will read one line at a time rather than one word at a time. So the solution, which looks kind of odd, is to pipe the file into the loop so it can be read line by line.
2. You need to quote `"$dir"` in the `ls` command so that the entire file name, whitespace and all, is treated as a single argument. If you don't do that `ls` will see two file names, `/var/tmp/old` and `files.txt`.

I'm probably going to get awarded the [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://www.partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). You can simplify this even further by removing the `cat`:

```
while read dir; do
    ls -al "$dir"
done < dirs.txt
```

This works because the **entire** `while` loop acts like one big command, so just like you can pipe `cat` into it, you can also use file redirection.

---

### Taking it even further...

Depending on how `dirs.txt` is generated you may just be able to get rid of it entirely and do everything in one command. If it's just a temporary file you could eliminate it by piping the command generates `dirs.txt` into the `while` loop directly, skipping the temporary file. For instance, replace

```
find /var -name '*old*' > dirs.txt
while read dir; do
    ls -al "$dir"
done < dirs.txt
```

with

```
find /var -name '*old*' | while read dir; do
    ls -al "$dir"
done
```

Pretend `find` is whatever command you're doing to generate the file list.

And actually, if you are in fact using `find` you can probably do everything in one big `find` command without any loops or anything! For example, the above code using `find` and `while` could be done with a single `find` command like this:

```
find /var -name '*old*' -exec ls -al {} \;
```

`find` is a really flexible command that can both search for files matching all kinds of complicated criteria, and pass those files as command-line arguments to other commands using the `-exec` option. When you use `-exec` the `{}` gets replaced with each file name.

Comment: Note that there's a potential gotcha with any of the "somecommand | while read..." versions: the while loop runs in a subshell, so any variables set in it vanish as soon as it exits. The "while ... done <dirs.txt" versions don't have this problem. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for some workarounds.

Comment: And bash's [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) allows you to avoid the temp file: `while read -r line; do ... done < <(find ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried to unzip a lot of files in a directory.  I found that since I had an alias for my "ls" I was causing myself unnecessary grief.  Once I fully-qualified the "ls" to be "/bin/ls" all was well with the world.

As for your specific problem, however, I'm not clear on why you want a file after a directory name when you might want a slash between them (i.e., /var/tmp/old/files.txt).

However, the fact you want to do "ls -al" doesn't fit either.  What you would seem to end up doing is a lot of "ls -al /var/tmp/old" (one per dirs.txt entry) and then a long listing of each *local* file named, as you have shown, files.txt and backups.bak.

Since this thread is nearly 2 years old, however, I imagine you're long past this problem :)